# Why does wget add html exentions to every file?

Tags: wget

I'm using following command to download all files from a server

```
wget -R "index.*" -m -np -e robots=off http://robotics.ethz.ch/~asl-datasets/ijrr_euroc_mav_dataset/
```

All files are recognized correctly, but wget adds `.html` to all files. For example: `ijrr_euroc_mav_dataset/calibration_datasets/cam_april/cam_april.bag` becomes `ijrr_euroc_mav_dataset/calibration_datasets/cam_april/cam_april.bag.html`

Why is that?

Also, wget creates the folder `~asl-datasets` which I didn't ask for. I just wanted to download all files below `ijrr_euroc_mav_dataset`.

Comment: It seems like you have a `~/.wgetrc` file that is setting some options. The `.html` extension is added using the `-E` option, which is not set in your command line. Please add either `--config=/dev/null` or `--no-config` to your command line and see the result

Comment: Thx, this solved it! Unfortunately I cannot accept comments as solution.

Comment: Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two separate questions, but is easy to answer. (I already solved this in the comments, but answering since that was apparently a spot-on observation).

The first is, why is Wget adding a `.html` suffix to your files. The reason for that is most likely that you have `adjust-extensions` in your `~/.wgetrc` file. This option is disabled by default for obvious reasons but is useful in many cases. Try modifying the ~/.wgetrc file or use `--no-config` (or `--config=/dev/null` if using a >5 year old version of Wget).

The second question is is why is Wget creating a directory. Well, the answer to that is simple. You asked to mirror a website which has that directory. You can use the `--cut-dirs` option to fine tune which directories you want Wget to create on disk. (In your cases, I think `--cut-dirs=2 --no-host-directories` might be appropriate since you don't care about preserving the directory structure. However remember that this means files in different directories with the same name will likely be overwritten